# Should I deallocate memory allocated for lpSecurityDescriptor of SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES when creating a new thread c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I have the following c++ code:

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saNullDACL;
saNullDACL.nLength = sizeof (SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
saNullDACL.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
saNullDACL.lpSecurityDescriptor = new SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
::InitializeSecurityDescriptor (saNullDACL.lpSecurityDescriptor, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
::SetSecurityDescriptorControl (saNullDACL.lpSecurityDescriptor  ,SE_DACL_PROTECTED,SE_DACL_PROTECTED);  
::SetSecurityDescriptorDacl (saNullDACL.lpSecurityDescriptor, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);

myThread = CreateThread(&saNullDACL, 0, myFunction, myStopEvent, 0, &myThreadID );
```

My question is - should I delete `saNullDACL.lpSecurityDescriptor` after new thread creation? (e.g. `delete saNullDACL.lpSecurityDescriptor`)
Thanks!

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Please tag only the one you actually use. And if you are using C++, a side note: it is recommended to use `std::thread` over the Windows specific `CreateThread`.

Comment: @wohlstad thanks for your comment, I've updated tags. But I can't use std::thread instead of CreateThread

Comment: @wohlstad the 4th parameter is passed to the thread, not the 1st parameter

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, I got that now. I guess the 1st paraneter also answers the question why use `CreateThread` over `std::thread` (that lacks the notion of security attributes).

Answer (score 3):

A simpler, and much more typical way of writing that code is as such:

```
SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd = {};
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saNullDACL = {};
saNullDACL.nLength = sizeof (SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
saNullDACL.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
saNullDACL.lpSecurityDescriptor = &sd;
```

No more heap allocations, no more worrying about freeing it up at the end!

Comment: @IInspectable, no, use-after-free is literally the code in OP's question. Leave your sarcasm at the door and crack open a book from time to time instead.

Comment: This is of course good advice but it doesn't really answer the question _"should I delete `saNullDACL.lpSecurityDescriptor` after new thread creation?"_.  I've already upvoted but I think the answer would be better addressing the actual question too.

Comment: The other answer already answered it, no need to repeat the same message. But if you need it explicitly spelled out, then yes, if you allocate it with `new`, you have to delete it with `delete`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since you are `new`'ing the descriptor, you must `delete` it when you are done using it, eg after `CreateThread()` returns. The thread does not need the descriptor anymore once the `HANDLE` is created.